# Socket Client Got Random Reset When Using Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I created java application to connect to multi TCP server that stream AIS data.

```
public static void proceed(String serverName, String[] serverDetail) {
    ..........
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port); InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // my code here
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    ..........
}
```

To make it possible to connect simulaneously, I am using multithreading. (I pun servers detail on a Map Object)

```
..........
serverMap.forEach((server_name, server_detail) -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
        proceed(server_name, server_detail);
    }).start();
});
..........
```

Running that application, I will get randomly resetted on my socket at some random *t* times. And resetted socket will never connects successfully again.

I check TCP data using WireShart to one of disconnected socket, and noticed that before server send **RST** signal, it receives some (or I can say lot) of **TCP Dup ACK**.

I tried first code in single thread to connect to a server, it ran stable. So, what I did wrong?

Comment: Probably nothing. Does the error always happen with the same server(s)?

Comment: Yes, it happened on same server(s). I am thinking that not my fault. Network factor?